# Store TextView on Button Click In onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, textview, bundle, onsaveinstancestate

I'm trying to save a TextView value that changes on a button click and keep it stored until I kill the app.
I am trying to use onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState to save and restore as long as the app is running. It doesn't work for me. Here is my code.

```
TextView questionText;
Button button ;
String perso1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    perso1 = MainActivity.perso;
    questionText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.perso);
    questionText.setText(perso1));
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_back_icon);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.settings);
   button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            resetConsent();
            questionText.setText("You clicked on the button");

        }
    });
}


@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    String newtext = questionText.getText().toString();
    outState.putString("TEXT", newtext);
}


@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    questionText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("TEXT"));
}
```

I'm trying to keep the new value of textview when I click on the button until I kill the app. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want the value of textview be restored after the app be killed and start again?

Comment: stored in the activity state as long as the app still running, once the app restarted it goes back to the original value

Comment: `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` are called when Android system kill and restart your Activity when possible, so they are not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel is what you need!

**Why**

> The `ViewModel` class is designed to store and manage UI-related data in a lifecycle conscious way. The `ViewModel` class allows data to survive configuration changes such as screen rotations.

It makes your life easier. You don't need to think on how to save it in youe `savedInstanceState`, but you can just store the String in your `ViewModel` (as a `LiveData`), then observe it.

With `LiveData`, you can change the value everytime the button clicked, and observe the value everytime it changes.

Comment: can you please give me an example on how to use it on my code?

Comment: sample code avalable from google codelab : https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-lifecycles/#0    
        GitHub link  :  https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/BasicSample

Answer (score 0):

You can always try to save state in a different way.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    String newtext = questionText.getText().toString();
    outState.putString("TEXT", newtext);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    //check if there was a previous saved state
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        //get the value you stored earlier in onSaveInstanceState()
        perso1 = savedInstanceState.getString("TEXT");
    }
    questionText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.perso);
    questionText.setText(perso1));

    //....
}
```

But this is just another way to save state.

I think i your error is explained below.

//you did this correctly- look, you set questionText here

```
onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    //set the questionText below
    questionText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("TEXT"));
}
```

but then in onCreate() you set the questionText again. This time to an incorrect value.

```
perso1 = MainActivity.perso;//< -- setting perso1 to nothing?
questionText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.perso);
questionText.setText(perso1));//<-- setting questionText again
```

> onRestoreInstanceState
>
> This method is called between onStart() and onPostCreate(Bundle).

In onSaveInstanceState() you did it correctly, in onRestoreInstanceState() you did it correctly, in onCreate() you set the value again to the wrong value.

Additionally read this when deciding to keep saving state this way or using a ViewModel

> For simple data, the activity can use the onSaveInstanceState() method and restore its data from the bundle in onCreate(), but this approach is only suitable for small amounts of data that can be serialized then deserialized, not for potentially large amounts of data like a list of users or bitmaps.

Comment: Oh yeah can you please reply here if i got it right or not?

Comment: So, i think this way wont work since the default textview value is always going to be in onCreate. Because onCreate will always override the saved value

Comment: Can't you just remove "perso1 = MainActivity.perso;"? What is perso anyways, you didn't show it. Also I got the lifecycle wrong. I removed it.

Comment: The "perso1" brings a value from Mainactivity and print it in this activity which called settingActivity. It holds a choice of the user. So i want to save new value in Textview and override perso1 and save it until i restart the app

Comment: Can't you use a bundle to transfer the value from MainActivity to settingActivity.? Then do everything else the same.